# Predicate Logic Proof $\forall x\neg P(x) ⊢\neg \exists xP(x)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I have been thinking about how I can prove something like this: $\forall x\neg P(x) ⊢\neg \exists xP(x)$. Unfortunately, I can’t seem to get anywhere...

I have tried assuming $\exists xP(x)$ to get a contradiction, but I only got the contradiction in a sub proof, so I am unsure about how to get $\neg \exists xP(x)$ at the end. How should I proceed? I used curly brackets to show where a sub proof starts and ends, I’m sorry for any confusion.

1. $∀x¬P(x)$ [premise]
2. $\qquad\{∃xP(x)$ [assume]
3. $\qquad\qquad\{P(a)$ [a]
4. $\qquad\qquad¬P(a)$ [∀ elimination]
5. $\qquad\qquad ⊥\}$
6. $\qquad?\}$
7. $¬∃xP(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $\exists E$ to justify $\bot$ without the assumption of $Pa$.

From https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/, the natural deduction proof editor and checker:

[image]